# Telegram Web App Bot, error redirecting to a new page on android

Tags: javascript, telegram-bot

I can't redirect user on new page with javascript variants code:

- `window.location.href=url`
- `window.location.replace (url)`
- `window.location.assign (url)`

The problem of redirect only on android, on other platforms there is no problem with going to another page.
How to fix it on android ?

View problem:
[when going to any page](https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/774759017951920158/1038805166553575467/image.png)

**Addition to the post:** the solution to the problem on android was using an iframe, it really helped. but now the problem is with the iframe itself on the iphone in Safari. when opening the webapp, js is not loaded. How to fix it ?

Comment: Well, I'm facing the same problem and notice this happen also with a basic HREF (and only on Android). And even with adding targer="_self". Strange...

Comment: https://bugs.telegram.org/c/16690

Comment: I found another way around it. Create a fully-formed form (including action & get values and a submit button) then change the action to desired page and use document.myForm.submit()

Answer (score 3):

In order to solve the problem you have to understand it. This happens on the Android version of Telegram in WebApps. When you click on a link, it does not open in the WebApp area but in the browser.
This browser is Telegram's internal or external browser, depending on what was indicated in Setting/Chat Setting/In-App Browser.
This bug occurs regardless of the link. So not just with your Javascript calls. A simple  produces the same effect.
It seems that it comes from a bug at the level of the WebView therefore in the code of Telegram. So a change in the code of your WebApp (another Javascript function for example) will not change anything.

**Solution**

The solution that I tested and that works is to use an iframe. Instead of having for example index.html which has links to page1.html and page2.html, you rename your index.html to menu.html and you make an index.html page which has an iframe containing menu.html.
If you put a borderless and full-surface iframe, the user won't notice anything.
And no need to go from menu to page1 or page2 with an iframe.src: direct Javascript links between pages that are in the iframe work perfectly, just like simple href links.

*Just one point: you have to perform a window.Telegram.WebApp.ready(); in your first page so the one with the iframe (and also in the others)*

Comment: iframe solved this problem, now the multi-page site is working fine. but there was a problem that the iframe is not supported via Safari, and on iphone devices, when logging into the webapp, all js stops working in the iframe. How can the problem be solved ?

Comment: @plaaarrr Try this https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250304102

Comment: this is not an appropriate solution to the problem, since I can't tell each user that he needs to change something in the settings, is there another way?

Answer (score 0):

Solution working at all tested platforms (Windows/Android/iOS):

- Add empty form, change action attribute to desired URL and submit.