Closing popup doesn't return to parent page in Safari Web App
I have a website on Next.js that uses the Telegram Login Widget. When a user clicks the "Login" button, a popup appears asking them to enter their mobile phone number and then waits for confirmation from the user in a Telegram dialog. After receiving the confirmation, the popup sends authentication data to my website and closes automatically.
This works well in most cases, but when the website is saved as a web app on an iOS device, after the popup closes, the last visited tab from Safari is displayed instead of my website.
At first, I thought the issue might be caused by the iframe that the widget used to display the "Login" button. However, after I rewrote the code and got rid off the iframe, the problem still persisted.
Also I tried to open the popup link in iframe but it sets 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.

Would you please add some code ?

Sure. Here is a code, that call the popup:
const popup = window.open(
"https://oauth.telegram.org/auth?bot_id=my_bot_id&origin=https://my_site_url&request_access=true&return_to=https://my_site__login_page_url",
telegram_oauth_bot + my_bot_id,
"width=800,height=500,left=0,top=0,status=0,location=0,menubar=0,toolbar=0"
);

Please check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/74459477/833395

The variant with iframe didn't work for me, unfortunately. But another solution from this issue, connected with form suited me well. Actually, I think, even simple link could be appropriate solution in my case. Thanks!
